# jquery ajax error

Tags: php, jquery

what data do i need to send from my server(php) so that jquery recognizes it as error and executes the error callback

Comment: Why not send a variable var `errorAjax = true;` and in your callback you check for that variable? `if(errorAjax) alert('an error has occurred');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?
header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could send any of the 5xx Server Error codes listed here back in your HTTP header.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Or else, you could just send back a message that states an error has occurred in the response, then check for that string on the client and handle that...

Comment: I would recommend the first suggestion - Sending a 5XX Error Code as the primary method, and then (if necessary) include content within the returned page/script/material detailing what the error was.